# random layout algorithm

Tags: algorithm, layout, graph

Given a number N and a rectangle, I'm looking for an algorithm that will 'randomly, but aesthetically' distribute N points in the rectangle.

This isn't really a graph layout problem, afaik, because it's not a graph - I just have N identical things (circles, pictures, whatever) I want to put in the rectangle. The result should be randomized, but still be aesthetically pleasing; things shouldn't bunch up too much, but also shouldn't be too 'orderly' (not sure how to define that precisely). N will typically be fairly small (< 10).

Any ideas/links?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to what's described [here](https://home.comcast.net/~davejanelle/packing.html): randomly distribute points, perturb them maximizing nearest neighbor distance with smaller and smaller increments for some iterations. The link describes doing millions of iterations, but I found after 8 or so, things look pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [Low-discrepancy Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) (aka Quasi-random sequences).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your rectangle has a grid. Every one of this objects will snap to that grid. But that would leave you with a equally distant objects, correct? Well, just add a random x,y offset to each of the object positions.

Comment: And each grid vertex can have only one thing? Hm, maybe. Although I think I can still get a lot of clustering, unless the grid is very coarse, and if it is, a lot of uniformity.

Comment: I know its very simple, but, to be honest, that's what I thought you were after. An image example would clarify your question.